# why does horizontal scrollbar appear

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

If you go to [this page](http://festivals.ie/festival/list?types=HEADLINE&types=MUSIC&types=COMEDY&types=SPORT&types=ARTS&types=FILM&types=FOOD_AND_DRINK&types=OTHER&location=IRELAND) (or indeed many other pages on the same site), and make the browser window narrow, the content area responds to the change in browser width. However, a horizontal scrollbar appears which suggest that there's some content outside the visible portion of the page, but there isn't.

Why does this horizontal scrollbar appear when there's no content (other than the background image) outside the visible section of the page, and how can I fix this problem?

### Update

I should have mentioned that I'm experiencing this issue when using Firefox.

Comment: I don't get a horizontal scrollbar, at least with IE9 which I'm forced to use at work ;)

Comment: I'm getting it with firefox!

Comment: i'm not getting it with chrome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the horizontal bar in Firefox 18.

You have a `div` with `id` `AutocompleteContainter_xxxxx` (last div on the page) which has it's `left` position set. When the window is resized the window this value should probably change to reflect the size of the window.

In my browser at fullscreen it renders as

```
<div id="AutocompleteContainter_c04ef" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 38px; left: 991.467px;">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I removed this element and it seemed to fix the problem. Well played, sir.